# Can´t create a column age from a column birthday_year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have a simple create table animal, for which **I pretend to fill the age column by inserting only the birtday_year.** 
I tried de getdate(), but can´t use a non-deterministic function, and even with other options, I end up with the simple one(from my point of view). But i can´t accomplish the requirements of this task.

Here is the code and one of the error:

```
create table animal
    ( nome varchar(255),
    VAT integer,
    species_name varchar(255),
     color varchar(255),
     gender varchar(255),
     birth_year integer,
     age generated always as ( 2018 - birth_year),
     primary key (nome,VAT),
     foreign key (VAT) references cliente(VAT) ,
     foreign key (species_name) references species(nome) );
```

---Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'generated always as ( 2018 - birth_year),   primary key (nome,VAT),   foreign ke' at line 8

I tried also:

```
create table animal
( nome varchar(255),
VAT integer,
species_name varchar(255),
 color varchar(255),
 gender varchar(255),
 birth_year integer,
 age  integer as ( 2018 - birth_year),
 primary key (nome,VAT),
 foreign key (VAT) references cliente(VAT) ,
 foreign key (species_name) references species(nome) );
```

--Error Code: 3105. The value specified for generated column 'age' in table 'animal' is not allowed.

Thanks for the help.
Best regards.

Comment: I would question whether it is sensible to try to store the `age`, since that is a value which changes as time passes, so the value may have been correct when it is stored, but not when it was retrieved. Better to just calculate it when you retrieve the record. Also to point out that birth_year is not going to give you an accurate value for age: someone born in 2017 could be zero or one years old.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you need to specify the type:

```
create table animal (
     nome varchar(255),
     VAT integer,
     species_name varchar(255),
     color varchar(255),
     gender varchar(255),
     birth_year integer,
     age int generated always as ( 2018 - birth_year),
     primary key (nome,VAT),
     foreign key (VAT) references cliente(VAT) ,
     foreign key (species_name) references species(nome)
);
```

Your version with:

```
age  integer as ( 2018 - birth_year),
```

Should also work, assuming your version of MySQL supports generated columns.

Note that the definition of `age` is rather specific.  Ideally, you would want:

```
year(curdate()) - birth_year
```

or something like that.

MySQL does not allow a volatile function such as `curdate()` to be used for a generated column.  To implement this functionality, you need to use a view:

```
create table v_animal as
    select a.*, (year(curdate()) - birth_year) as age
    from animal;
```